# How to check point intersection with bbox made from two points?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geometry, intersection

I have two points which represents lower left and upper right point of BBOX.
I have one point which SHOULD be somewhere inside and I want to test it.

I have all of them as 'geometry(POINT, 4326)' data type.

When I try functions:

```
ST_MakeBox2D( geom4326ur, geom4326ll )
ST_Envelope ( ST_MakeBox2D( geom4326ur, geom4326ll ) 
Box2D
```

I get only linestring geometry connecting these two points.
I don't get 4 points of box which I need to transform them to polygon and then check with ST_Intersect if all points are inside their bounding boxes.

Can you help me solve this? I would like to have most effective solution - I am running this on millions of points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ST_MakeBox2D already returns a geometry that is a polygon for PostGIS. The right syntax has points in lower left-upper right order but function does not seem to be strict with that.

```
SELECT
ST_MakeBox2D(
ST_GeomFromText('POINT (0 0)'),
ST_GeomFromText('POINT (1 1)'));

"BOX(0 0,1 1)"

SELECT
ST_MakeBox2D(
ST_GeomFromText('POINT (1 1)'),
ST_GeomFromText('POINT (0 0)'));

"BOX(0 0,1 1)"

SELECT ST_AsText(
ST_MakeBox2D(
ST_GeomFromText('POINT (0 0)'),
ST_GeomFromText('POINT (1 1)')));

"POLYGON((0 0,0 1,1 1,1 0,0 0))"
```

Your ST_MakeBox2D should work both alone and inside ST_Envelope. Could it be that your coordinates do not make a box but either X- or Y-coordinates are the same like in this example?

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Envelope(
ST_MakeBox2D(
ST_GeomFromText('POINT (0 0)'),
ST_GeomFromText('POINT (0 1)'))));

"LINESTRING(0 0,0 1)"
```

Comment: This is correct. There were problems in my geometries - some of the X or Y were same which resulted in linestrings.